# Command works in mongodb compass but not in php

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, compass

```
_id:1
email:"j@g.com"
```

This is my collection. When I write

```
{ email: /^J/i  }
```

in compass it works absolutely fine, but in php

```
$user_collection->find(
    ["email" => ['$regex' => "/^j/i"]]
);
```

finds nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `/^J/i`, the `i` is an option flag to request case-insensitive search.

When using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) you need to use a separate options field:

```
['$regex' => "^j", '$options'=>"i"]
```

Comment: `$user_collection->find(
    ["email" => ['$regex' => "^j", '$options'=>'i']]
);`
This is working for me. (excluding "/")

Comment: Thanks @TanmoonTaz, I had the same problem trying to use `/` in a MongoDb regex query `{ "values.QID24_TEXT": { $regex: /.*98763.*/, $options: "si" } }` (this throws an error in MongoDb Atlas). After I removed the `/` and placing quotes around the regex expression, the updated query `{ "values.QID24_TEXT": { $regex: ".*98763.*", $options: "si" } }` returned the expected document.